# Serving 2 django sites with the same code

Tags: django, apache, wsgi

I'm serving a django site with apache and wsgi using an apache config as follow:

```
  Alias /media/ /var/www/media/
  Alias /files/ /var/www/files/
  WSGIDaemonProcess fc processes=5 threads=5 display-name=%{GLOBAL}
  WSGIProcessGroup fc
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/path/to/django.wsgi
```

The app is served in the root directory of the host. I'd like now to change this so I can serve it at http://host/app1 and another one, with a different django setting, at http://host/app2

How can I change the config to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a set of `WSGI*` directives for each project.  That second parameter to `WSGIScriptAlias` tells Apache where the project lives in the tree; WSGI removes this prefix before the URL is passed to Django's URL resolver.

For example:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess app1 threads=15
WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /var/www/django_project1/django.wsgi
<Location /app1>
WSGIProcessGroup app1
</Location>

WSGIDaemonProcess app2 threads=15
WSGIScriptAlias /app2 /var/www/django_project2/django.wsgi
<Location /app2>
WSGIProcessGroup app2
</Location>
```

I haven't tried to optimize this; there may be a better way. But this should get you running.

Comment: Original example here was wrong in a number of ways. WSGISocketPrefix as used was wrong as should only occur once and only used in certain cases and not always. Setting user/group to 'apache' is redundant as that is the default and 'apache' as a user may not be valid on many systems. WSGIProcessGroup had to be scoped by Location context so only applies to the one application.

Comment: Thanks for the fixes.  I was adapting a working single-site setup I have which itself has not been optimized; for example, the user and group was set that way because I didn't know if the Apache install (which I don't control) used "apache" or "nobody" for its user. The socket prefix was set because the default isn't where the sysadmin wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to make other folder with second `settings.py` and create symbolic links to your apps, locales, static, templates, urls.py etc.

I have multiple projects using same apps so I've put them in standalone folder which i added to python path. I also use same database for both sites, but i have different SITE_ID so i can specify wchich site i want to have my content. This way i can have totally different websites using different templates, styles and images having the same content. If JS scripts are the same on both sites i create a symlink.